# How to use boost::asio::io_service::run_one()

Tags: exception, boost, boost-asio, handler

I was reading up on [boost::asio::io_service::run_one()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run_one.html) and am confused by what it means by the function block. What has been blocked and where is the handler defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was reading up on boost::asio::io_service::run_one() and am confused by what it means by the function block. What has been blocked

Blocked means `run_one()` blocks until it completes one handler.

> and where is the handler defined?

It isn't. [Logically it's described in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html). A handler is whatever action is pending in the service. So, if you do:

```
 void foo() { /*.... */ }
 void bar() { /*.... */ }

 io_service svc;
 svc.post(foo);
 svc.post(bar);
```

Now the first time you call

```
 svc.run_one();
```

blocks until `foo` is completed. The second time

```
 svc.run_one();
```

will block until `bar` is completed. After that, `run_one()` will NOT block and just return 0. If you make the service stay around, e.g.:

```
 io_service::work keep_around(svc);
 svc.run_one();
```

would block until some other action was posted.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last use case?

Comment: The linked documentation does, see also [work](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html). The short summary is that `run*()` and `poll*()` always return once all work is done. `work` is an "artificial" piece of work that prevents that. It's not _essentially_ related to the answer, just added because it shows that `run_one()` could block for indefinitely, not just the time to run a particular task.

Comment: I'm sorry, do you have a clearer explanation on the linked documentation? I might not fully understand it, and it seems my implementation of run_one() did block indefinitely.

Comment: You should probably make a clearer question :) Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve